# How to get the difference between two arrays but keeping repeat objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, lodash

Lets say that you have two arrays with objects, **Array 1** and **Array 2**. The issue I am having is finding the **exact** difference between the two arrays, which may include elements that are seemingly equal to each. In this example, I commented the specific objects in each array.

Think of this in terms of having a shopping cart with repeat items, but you can only redeem one item. So `//number 4` is one of the repeat items, but you still need it in **Array 3**

---

**ARRAY 1**

```
[
  { // number 1
    item_id: 4,
    total_price: 2.71
  },
  { // number 2
    item_id: 2,
    total_price: 3.71
  },
  { // number 3
    item_id: 4,
    total_price: 1.71
  },
  { // number 4
    item_id: 4,
    total_price: 2.71
  }
]
```

---

**ARRAY 2**

```
[
  { // number 1
    item_id: 4,
    total_price: 2.71
  }
]
```

How do I find the difference between these two arrays, **Array 3**?? And would it be best to have a unique key on each object to compare easier? Doing this in javascript/node and mainly using lodash.

**ARRAY 3**

```
[
  { // number 2
    item_id: 2,
    total_price: 3.71
  },
  { // number 3
    item_id: 4,
    total_price: 1.71
  },
  { // number 4
    item_id: 4,
    total_price: 2.71
  }
]
```

Comment: I don't get why "number 4" is in the result array? Is the elements index also counted as a difference?

Comment: @sboesch I edited the question, but think of this in terms of lets say you have a cart with repeat items, but you can only redeem one item. So `//number 4` is one of the repeat items, but you still need it in **Array 3**

Comment: I'm sorry, but what? So what actually do you want to achieve.. if the same object is present in both arrays, drop it from the results array?

Comment: @KornholioBeavis see above :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using [lodash#differenceWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#differenceWith).

```
function difference(arr1, arr2) {
  var found = {};
  return _.differenceWith(arr1, arr2, function(x, y) {
    var isDiff = _.isEqual(x, y) && !found[x.id];
    found[x.id] = true;
    return isDiff;
  });
}
```

```js
var array1 = [
  { // number 1
    item_id: 4,
    total_price: 2.71
  },
  { // number 2
    item_id: 2,
    total_price: 3.71
  },
  { // number 3
    item_id: 4,
    total_price: 1.71
  },
  { // number 4
    item_id: 4,
    total_price: 2.71
  }
];

var array2 = [
  { // number 1
    item_id: 4,
    total_price: 2.71
  }
];

function difference(arr1, arr2) {
  var found = {};
  return _.differenceWith(arr1, arr2, function(x, y) {
    var isDiff = _.isEqual(x, y) && !found[x.id];
    found[x.id] = true;
    return isDiff;
  });
}

console.log(difference(array1, array2));
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Best answer with the cleanest code!! In the end, I have learned that finding the difference between two arrays with a unique identifier is the way to go :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with something like this using lodash:

```
array2.forEach(el => {
  let index = _.findIndex(array1, e => e.item_id === el.item_id);
  if (index >= 0) {
    array1.splice(index, 1);
  }
});
```

Now your `array1` will have the correct values removed. If you want to keep the original `array1` then copy it first and work on the copy:

```
let array3 = _.clone(array1);
array2.forEach(el => {
  let index = _.findIndex(array3, e => e.item_id === el.item_id);
  if (index >= 0) {
    array3.splice(index, 1);
  }
});
```

Now you have the result in `array3`.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to subtract Array2 from Array1?

A bit ugly but it works:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
    var arrAElement = arrayA[i];

    arrayC.push(arrAElement);

    for(var j = 0; j < arrayB.length; j++) {
        var arrBElement = arrayB[j];

        if(arrAElement.item_id == arrBElement.item_id && 
           arrAElement.total_price == arrBElement.total_price) {
            arrayB.splice(j,1);
            arrayC.pop();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Working demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/a0180jdf/

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through Array1 and check for each entry if the item is present in Array2, if not put it in Array3.

Code would be something like:

```
for (var elt : array1) {
   var eltFound = false;
   var i = 0;

   // Loops in array2 to find element
   while (!eltFound && i < array2.length) {
      if (array2[i] == elt) { // maybe here do the check with item_id <-> elt[0]
         eltFound = true;
      }
   }

   if (!eltFound) {
      array3.push(elt);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS only, I would rather use `slice` and kick the items one by one:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < array1.length ; i++) {
  for(var j = 0 ; j < array2.length ; j++) {
    if(array1[i].item_id == array2[j].item_id && array1[i].total_price == array2[j].total_price) {
      array1.splice(i,1);
      array2.splice(j,1);
      i--;
      j--;
      break;
    }
  }
}
console.log(array1);
```

`array1` now contains the values from the difference. I just tested with your data and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows;

```js
function removeDupes(a){
  var hash = a.reduce(function(h,o){
                        var k = Object.keys(o).reduce((p,c) => "" + o[p] + o[c]);
                        h[k] || (h[k] = o);
                        return h;
                      },{});
  return Object.keys(hash)
               .map(k => hash[k]);
}

var data = [
  { // number 1
    item_id: 4,
    total_price: 2.71
  },
  { // number 2
    item_id: 2,
    total_price: 3.71
  },
  { // number 3
    item_id: 4,
    total_price: 1.71
  },
  { // number 4
    item_id: 4,
    total_price: 2.71
  }
],
 result = removeDupes(data);
 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the origin `arr1` values, you can use `_.cloneDeep(arr1)`

```js
var arr1 = [{ // number 1
    item_id: 4,
    total_price: 2.71
}, { // number 2
    item_id: 2,
    total_price: 3.71
}, { // number 3
    item_id: 4,
    total_price: 1.71
}, { // number 4
    item_id: 4,
    total_price: 2.71
}];

let arr2 = [{ // number 1
    item_id: 4,
    total_price: 2.71
}];

// Loops through `arr2` and compare each element with `arr1`
arr2.forEach(el2 => arr1.every((el1, index) =>
    // Compare `el2` with every `el1` in `arr1`
    // If `el2` === `el1`, return true to continue every loop
    // Otherwise, splice it out from the curren `index` and return false
    // to stop the every loop.
    el1.item_id !== el2.item_id || el1.total_price !== el2.total_price ? 
    true : arr1.splice(index, 1) && false
));

console.log(arr1);
```